# Free online viewer for a PDF brochure?

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for a free online PDF viewer with basic functionality: page flipping, zoom in and zoom out.

Flash-free solution would be great.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Google Docs, G Suite,  iCloud, & OneDrive all should have PDF viewers / editors that can do what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for an embeddable solution for a website, something like FlowPaper. And no, Google Docs etc. can't do this.